# Xamarin.Forms ZXing.Net.Mobile loosing current page after scan result on iOS 10

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I have implemented ZXing.Net.Mobile for scanning bar codes.

On Android it's working fine, on iOS 10 after reading a barcode the function "OnScanResult" is fired and executes the command Navigation.PopAsync() which closes the scanning page but after a second it closes also the current page where I have displayed the result !

```
        MyTapScan.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
        {                
            await MyBtScan.ScaleTo(1.20, 100, Easing.Linear);             
            await MyBtScan.ScaleTo(1, 100, Easing.Linear);
            await Task.Delay(50);
            //--------------------------------------------
            MyAppLib.MyAppUtilitiesBarCodeReader MyBarCodeReader = new MyAppLib.MyAppUtilitiesBarCodeReader();                                
            var MyScannerPage = MyBarCodeReader.GetBarCodeReaderPage();
            //--------------------------------------------
            MyScannerPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
                //Stop scanning
                MyScannerPage.IsScanning = false;
                //Pop the page and show the result
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Navigation.PopAsync();
                    MyMachSerialNumber.Text = result.Text;
                });
            };
            //--------------------------------------------
            //Display scanner
            await Navigation.PushAsync(MyScannerPage);
        };
```

Please please help..!! :)

Comment: Try this - don't call Navigation.PopAsync();

Comment: I tried but if I don't call Navigation.PopAsync() it doesn't close the camera page "MyScannerPage" and never goes back to the initial page where I want to display the bar code result...

Comment: Does it happen only on iOS10 or on iOS9 too?

Comment: I don't know as I don't have iOS 9, I have iOS 10 only..I see if I can find out someone with iOS 9

Comment: Just find out if I start the app the first time it's working fine, but if I try to scan a second time a bar code then I got this problem. If I close the app and remove it from the memory on my iPhone and start again from fresh, it's working the first time but again from the second scanning always closes the camera page and the page from where I call the camera.

Comment: Just find out for some reason the function MyScannerPage.OnScanResult is fired twice or even more times, for this reason closes other pages as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have introduced a new variable to check if the scanning was already fired and now it's working fine and as expected.
This is the code:

```
MyTapScan.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
        {                
            await MyBtScan.ScaleTo(1.20, 100, Easing.Linear);             
            await MyBtScan.ScaleTo(1, 100, Easing.Linear);
            await Task.Delay(50);
            bool MyIsScanning = true;
            //--------------------------------------------
            MyAppLib.MyAppUtilitiesBarCodeReader MyBarCodeReader = new MyAppLib.MyAppUtilitiesBarCodeReader();                                
            var MyScannerPage = MyBarCodeReader.GetBarCodeReaderPage();
            //--------------------------------------------
            MyScannerPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
                //Stop scanning
                MyScannerPage.IsScanning = false;
                //Pop the page and show the result
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    if (MyIsScanning == true)
                    {
                        MyIsScanning = false;
                        MyMachSerialNumber.Text = result.Text;
                        Navigation.PopAsync();
                    }                                                
                });
            };
            //--------------------------------------------
            //Display scanner
            await Navigation.PushAsync(MyScannerPage);
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time MyTapScan.Tapped is called you are subscribing to MyScannerPage.OnScanResult so if you tap button 5 times your OnScanResult will be called 5 times. I hope now you know how to solve that.

One of possible solutions:
Take your OnScanResult delegate and make it separate function, let say ScanFinished. Then instead of

`MyScannerPage.OnScanResult += (result)`

do

```
MyScannerPage.OnScanResult -= ScanFinished; 
MyScannerPage.OnScanResult += ScanFinished;
```

Then you can be sure the event unsubscribed before you subscribe to it again