# ZXing OnScanResult is called twice on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing

I have a Xamarin.Forms application. I use ZXing.Mobile.Forms to scan a QR code; however, when I point the camera to a QR code the `OnScanResult` event is called twice. This is my code, a faithful reproduction of the one suggested [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile):

```
    private async void onScanQRCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage(); // executed just once

        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false; // executed twice (confused)

            // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                Navigation.PopAsync();
                /* Business code */
                Account scannedAccount = URLInterpreter.Accept(result.Text);
                ViewModel.ProcessNewAccount(scannedAccount);
                /* End of business code */
            });
        };

        // Navigate to our scanner page
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
    }
```

And this is the XAML for the button that calls the method above:

```
        <Button x:Name="btnScanCode" Text="Scan QR Code" Clicked="onScanQRCode" />
```

Any pointers?

**UPDATE**
Apparently, this only happens when I'm debugging the app and the phone is connected to Visual Studio. If I launch the app without attaching the debugger, the event is fired once.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, this answer helped me to resolve it: [Xamarin.Forms ZXing.Net.Mobile loosing current page after scan result on iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295219/xamarin-forms-zxing-net-mobile-loosing-current-page-after-scan-result-on-ios-10)

Your code should be:

```
private async void onScanQRCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
    bool scanFinished = false;

    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
        // Stop scanning
        scanPage.IsScanning = false;

        // Pop the page and show the result
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            if (!scanFinished)
            {               
                scanFinished = true;
                Account scannedAccount = URLInterpreter.Accept(result.Text);
                ViewModel.ProcessNewAccount(scannedAccount);
                await Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        });
    };

    // Navigate to our scanner page
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
}
```

I tested on iOS 10.3.1 and ZXing.Net.Forms.Mobile 2.2.9.