# Xamrin ZXing for iPhone does not fire event for scan result, but works on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, nuget, visual-studio-2019

Question about Xamarin App with Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin using nuget ZXing barcode scanner library.
I try the code in https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile.
It works on Android, but not on iPhone. The scanner view shows up, but there is never a result event. 
I implemented all as described. I tried several versions of nuget packages. I could not find a solution on google, i tried many suggestions.

If no solution is found, Is there a good alternative for ZXamarin?

Comment: Did you try to use [ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms/3.0.0-beta5) nuget package or  [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Mobile/3.0.0-beta5)?

Comment: I use both of them.

Comment: Myabe [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295219/xamarin-forms-zxing-net-mobile-loosing-current-page-after-scan-result-on-ios-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295219/xamarin-forms-zxing-net-mobile-loosing-current-page-after-scan-result-on-ios-10).

Comment: Is not the same, there the result is scanned, but in my case the result is never scanned.

Comment: Please [check the readme.txt](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#ios) of the project.

Comment: Ther is now additional info in the readme i have not considered.

Comment: I will work for more tests and hope I can get one.

Comment: To Perry Qian-MSFT: I don't understand your comment, du you want more code?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please try to share a reproduce sample with us or community members to help us troubleshoot it.

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue i got the same problem ?

Comment: No still waiting for a solution. I can not give more details, because the default solution does not work on github. Mai be a problem with visual studio? I test with hot reload on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem myself.
I updated two times to Visual Studio Community 2019, is now Version 16.8.4.
Then I tried with Visual Studio for Mac and it worked, also on Windows Version.
I connected the Device directly with USB on the Mac.
So i'm not sure what was wrong.